# Exclude final row during csv file dump into google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am extracting a csv file from my Gmail and dumping it into a Google Sheet using this Google App Script.

But the csv file I am receiving has a 'total' towards the end of it, I would like to load all the data except last row from the csv file i.e., n-1

How do I tweak the below code to such that the code excludes last delimited value

```js
function importfromGmail() {
  var sheetName = "Stackoverflow"; // Please set the tab name you want to overwrite the data.
  var threads = GmailApp.search("label:Stackoverflow"); // Please set here.

  var messages = threads[0].getMessages();
  var message = messages[messages.length - 1];
  var attachment = message.getAttachments()[0];

  var data = [];
  Logger.log("ContentType: "+attachment.getContentType())
  //Logger.log(Utilities.parseCsv(attachment.getDataAsString(), ","));
  data = Utilities.parseCsv(attachment.getDataAsString(), ",");
  
  Logger.log(data.length)
  if (data.length > 0) {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
    Logger.log(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getUrl());
    sheet.clearContents().clearFormats();
    sheet.getRange(1, 1, data.length, data[0].length).setValues(data);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your situation, how about modifying your script as follows?

#### From:

```
data = Utilities.parseCsv(attachment.getDataAsString(), ",");
```

#### To:

```
data = Utilities.parseCsv(attachment.getDataAsString(), ",");
data.pop();
```

- By `pop()`, the last element is removed from `data`.

#### Reference:

- [pop()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop)